# How to create a transparent gradient on the color gradient under angle 90

Tags: android, background, android-viewpager, gradient

I'm trying to create some gradient to get soft edges of my items in ViewPager while scrolling and swiping.

Tell me please is it possible to create something like this?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: This is a DOUBLE gradient (= 2 gradients overlaid)

Comment: Yes, the first - color from the bottom to the top, the second - transparency from the right side to the left side or from the left to the right.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to do with code, with XML it would require messy nesting. It could be achieved in code using [RadialGradient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RadialGradient.html) or [LinearGradient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient.html).

I think the simplest option is to use a LinearGradient at 45 degrees from #FF01374F to #1191D4F4 (with an 8 digit hex code the first two characters are opacity). This *won't* give you exactly what you've asked for but it's the simplest way I know to get a close as possible.